# Java - regular expression to remove content between brackets as long as it contains specific string

Tags: java, regex

I have a following sentence:

```
String sentence = "FirstName LastName (pronounced as: X) (born 1 June 1900)";
```

I need regex which will get rid of everything between brackets (including brackets) as long as text between brackets contains word: **pronounced**.

Producing an output like this:

```
"FirstName LastName (born 1 June 1900)"
```

Please let me know how... thanks.

Comment: Those aren't brackets `{}`. Those are parentheses `()`

Comment: @pguardiario - [That's only true for American English—and only the parentheses part. `{}` are called braces, `[]` are brackets.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket)

Comment: @DaoWen, For us, `{}` are brackets. Stick around and you'll learn a few things.

Comment: @pguardiario - Well, you'd better tell the guys who wrote the Java Language Specification, because apparently [they got it wrong too!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2) *"A block is a sequence of statements, local class declarations, and local variable declaration statements within **braces**."* Besides, my original point that I wanted to make was that StackOverflow is an international community, and we should be familiar with some non-American-English terms. (P.S. Yes, I noticed your profile says you're from the Philippines.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
(?=\\([^()]*?pronounced)\\([^)]+\\)
```

And an empty replacement string.

Java code:

```
String input = "FirstName LastName (pronounced as: X) (born 1 June 1900)";
String result = input.replaceAll("(?=\\([^()]*?pronounced)\\([^)]+\\)", "");
```

Comment: Nice, that worked nicely. How would it work with nesting... sometimes my text could have something like this: String input = "FirstName LastName ((pronounced as: X) (born 1 June 1900))"; . In this case I need to keep (born 1 June 1900). Can you help?

Comment: @jjj With the current expression this will leave you with `FirstName LastName  (born 1 June 1900))`. How do you want the actual output ?

Comment: @jjj I have modified my answer a little bit, please check edit.

Comment: @Sniffer - Your first regex `(?=\\(.*?pronounced)\\([^)]+\\)` matches '`( should not match )` (pronounced should match ) '. The second one is better.

Comment: @sln You are correct. Thank you for your observation. I will remove the first expression.

Comment: @jjj So do you have any more problems or the expression worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

A pattern like this should work:

```
\((?=[^)]*pronounced)[^)]+\)
```

This will match a literal `(` followed by one or more characters other than `)` followed by a literal `)`, but ONLY if it also contains a literal `pronounced`.

Don't forget to escape the `\` in a Java string literal:

```
output = input.replaceAll("\\((?=[^)]*pronounced)[^)]+\\)", "");
```

Comment: Not bad, but the lookahead is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

No need for lookahead, negated char class does the job:

```
/\([^)]*pronounced[^)]*\)/
```

Comment: ...and if you want only the innermost set of possibly nested brackets, lookaheads still aren't necessary: `\([^()]*pronounced[^()]*\)`.  Why is everyone else so stuck on lookaheads?

Comment: Just curious, could this `/\([^)]*?pronounced[^)]*\)/` reduce backtracking?

Comment: @Alan Moore - I think when assertions are understood, they tend to be overused by people. It could be noticable extra processing.

Comment: If `pronounced` always appears much closer to the opening `(` than to the ending `)`, the reluctant `*?` might make a noticeable difference.  But in general, I think changing both instances of `[^)]*` to `[^()]*` will do a lot more good performance-wise, because it will cause it to fail faster when no match is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.replaceAll("\\((?=[^()]*pronounced).*?\\)","");
```